# Heroku postgres crached

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, dyno

I want to run some python code from a remote server in order to expose the database in output of this code. Do you have an idea of what is my probleme ?

- I'm connected to the heroku posgresql apps-on and a dyno.
- My requirements.txt is ok.
- My Procfile is: worker: python ponts.py (Ive try with app)
- my heroku logs are :

```
2023-04-04T16:40:32.018818+00:00 app[worker.1]: ('Pont sur le torrent Nervi', None, "Maçonnerie2 arches (1 principale arc rampant), dos d'âne", 'Pont piétonnierVia Roberto Sarfatti - Via Odoardo GanduccioNervia', 'Gênes44°\xa023′\xa004,4″\xa0N, 9°\xa002′\xa000,3″\xa0E', 'Ligurie')
2023-04-04T16:40:32.018826+00:00 app[worker.1]: ('Pont Morandi (viaduc du Polcevera)', '1100', 'HaubanéTablier, pylônes et câbles béton202+208+142+73', 'Autostrada A10Route européenne 25Route européenne 80Gare de Gênes', 'Gênes44°\xa025′\xa030,1″\xa0N, 8°\xa053′\xa026,7″\xa0E', 'Ligurie')
2023-04-04T16:40:32.018827+00:00 app[worker.1]: ('Viaduc de Bisagno', '593', 'Poutre-caissonBéton précontraint', 'Autostrada A12Route européenne 80Bisagno', 'Gênes44°\xa026′\xa004,2″\xa0N, 8°\xa057′\xa026″\xa0E', 'Ligurie')
2023-04-04T16:40:32.018835+00:00 app[worker.1]: ('Viaduc de Nervi', '422', 'Poutre-caissonBéton précontraint', 'Autostrada A12Route européenne 80Nervi', 'Gênes44°\xa023′\xa033″\xa0N, 9°\xa002′\xa028″\xa0E', 'Ligurie')
2023-04-04T16:40:32.229064+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2023-04-04T16:40:32.269439+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

my python code (without the creation of the dataframe df_filtered is :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import psycopg2
import datetime

# Connexion à la base de données
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host=,
    database=,
    user=,
    password=,
    port=
)
# Insertion des données dans la base de données
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eonsight2 (nom VARCHAR(255), longueur VARCHAR(255), bridge_type VARCHAR(255), voies VARCHAR(255), localisation VARCHAR(255), region VARCHAR(255))")
for index, row in df_filtered.iterrows():
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO eonsight2 (nom, longueur, bridge_type, voies, localisation, region) "
                "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                (row['nom'], row['longueur'], row['bridge_type'], row['voie_portee_franchie'],
                 row['localisation'], row['region']))
conn.commit()

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM eonsight2;') # On récupère les valeurs de la base de données
for row in cur.fetchall(): # On affiche les valeurs
    print(row)
# Fermeture de la connexion
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I tried to mofify the code, to modify the Procfile (ex : worker: python bridges.py, web: python bridges.py,...).
I want that when I launch the application, the database is displayed.

Comment: Look at the PostgreSQL log.

Comment: Nothing here shows a crash. "Exited code 0" indicates success. Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: Note that this code runs, then finishes. That makes it a poor fit for a worker process. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Hello @Chris and thanks for your comment. I'm trying to see my data base online but after the "Deploy a GitHub branch", I've open the app and there is an Application error

Comment: What do you expect the application to do? This code just creates a table, inserts some data, retrieves the data, and prints it.

Comment: Thanks again Chris. I want to execute the code from a remote server (Heroku) then expose the database. For me, after launching the application, I should be able to find the table somewhere but I don't know where.

Comment: Actually, the only prints that I found are in the logs.